# Keeping CSS files separate with webpacker:compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js, webpacker

I have a Rails/Webpacker/Vue app where I want to have different styles on each page.  That may look like this:

```
// page-a.vue
<style lang="scss">
  @import './stylesheets/a';
</style>



// page-b.vue
<style lang="scss">
  @import './stylesheets/b';
</style>
```

These stylesheets have completely separate rules that should not mix.

In development with `webpack-dev-server`, the stylesheets remain separate as expected.  However, when `webpacker:compile` is run, the stylesheets merge and all the CSS is used by both files.

---

Because of this, deploying to production is causing my application to look vastly different than in development.

How can I keep CSS files separate when using `webpacker:compile`?

Comment: What are your pack tags/entry points looking like? I kept mine separate for this effect.

Comment: @CD-RUM There is only one entrypoint, my `application.html.erb`.  From there, the rest of the application/routing is handled by Vue.

Answer (score 0):

With .vue files you can use scoped css. This way css files will be included as separate style tags by the loader.

`<style scoped>
.example {
  color: red;
}
</style>`

Take a look here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html

Comment: My apologies, I should've elaborated that I need the CSS to effect every and all sub-components in use. These Vue files I'm working with are the entry points to the main site and the admin portal, if that adds clarity

Comment: Btw: as far as I know web pack dev server inlines the styles when auto updating. This why its working as you mention.